# An fast algorithm for sorting and shuffling equal valued entries (preferably by STL's)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, shuffle

I'm currently developing stochastic optimization algorithms and have encountered the following issue (which I imagine appears also in other places): It could be called **totally unstable partial sort**:

> Given a container of size n and a comparator, such that entries may be equally valued. 
>   Return the best k entries, but if values are equal, it should be (nearly) equally probable to receive any of them.

*(output order is irrelevant to me, i.e. equal values completely among the best k need not be shuffled. To even have **all** equal values shuffled is however a related, interesting question and would suffice!)*

A very (!) inefficient way would be to use `shuffle_randomly` and then `partial_sort`, but one actually only needs to shuffle the block of equally valued entries "at the selection border" *(resp. all blocks of equally valued entries, both is much faster)*. Maybe that Observation is where to start...

I would very much prefer, if someone could provide a solution with STL algorithms (or at least to a large portion), both because they're usually very fast, well encapsulated and OMP-parallelized.

Thanx in advance for any ideas!

Comment: STL algorithms are unlikely OMP-parallelized, which compiler are you generally using that would promise such a thing ? Also, generally people aim at *reproductible* behavior, which means **stable sorting**. Indeed the STL provides `std::sort`, `std::stable_sort`, `std::partial_sort` and `std::nth_element`, but nothing like what you are looking for (directly).

Comment: Usual g++ with -fopenmp ... you have the choice between using   -D_GLIBCXX_PARALLEL for globally parallelized STL's (when dubbed sensful at this place by the compiler) or __gnu_parallel:: namespaces for calling the parallelized versions directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really mean that output order is irrelevant, then you want `std::nth_element`, rather than `std::partial_sort`, since it is generally somewhat faster. Note that `std::nth_element` puts the n<sup>th</sup> element in the right position, so you can do the following, which is 100% standard algorithm invocations (warning: not tested very well; fencepost error possibilities abound):

```
template<typename RandomIterator, typename Compare>
void best_n(RandomIterator first,
            RandomIterator nth,
            RandomIterator limit,
            Compare cmp) {
  using ref = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference;
  std::nth_element(first, nth, limit, cmp);
  auto p = std::partition(first, nth, [&](ref a){return cmp(a, *nth);});
  auto q = std::partition(nth + 1, limit, [&](ref a){return !cmp(*nth, a);});
  std::random_shuffle(p, q);  // See note
}
```

The function takes three iterators, like `nth_element`, where `nth` is an iterator to the n<sup>th</sup> element, which means that it is `begin() + (n - 1))`.

**Edit**: Note that this is different from most STL algorithms, in that it is effectively an *inclusive* range. In particular, it is UB if `nth == limit`, since it is required that `*nth` be valid. Furthermore, there is no way to request the `best 0` elements, just as there is no way to ask for the 0<sup>th</sup> element with `std::nth_element`. You might prefer it with a different interface; do feel free to do so.

Or you might call it like this, after requiring that `0 < k <= n`:

```
best_n(container.begin(), container.begin()+(k-1), container.end(), cmp);
```

It first uses `nth_element` to put the "best" `k` elements in positions `0..k-1`, guaranteeing that the k<sup>th</sup> element (or one of them, anyway) is at position `k-1`. It then repartitions the elements preceding position `k-1` so that the equal elements are at the end, and the elements following position `k-1` so that the equal elements are at the beginning. Finally, it shuffles the equal elements.

`nth_element` is `O(n)`; the two `partition` operations sum up to `O(n)`; and `random_shuffle` is `O(r)` where `r` is the number of equal elements shuffled. I think that all sums up to `O(n)` so it's optimally scalable, but it may or may not be the fastest solution.

---

Note: You should use `std::shuffle` instead of `std::random_shuffle`, passing a uniform random number generator through to `best_n`. But I was too lazy to write all the boilerplate to do that and test it. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for this perfectly worked-out solution! Very neat to use the ad-hoc predicate "=a" for partition; I gotta use lambda more often ;-) Also, I thought the first...nth line partition needs less, as it is already sorted, but you saved that time (and more) using n-th...I think I overlooked that one simply because I could not image how the n-th is (ambiguosly)defined if elements are equal valued ;-) ;-)

Comment: Just for later readers: For me it required instead of the "using" the following line: "typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomIterator>::reference ref;"

Comment: @user1814663: `using` is the new form of type aliases (which also allows template aliases), it might be that the compiler you use does not support it (at least here) for now.

Comment: +1: very clever use of `std::partition`. One limitation I can see immediately is if `nth == limit`: `*nth` might then be undefined behavior. It might be worth optimizing it out anyway: `if (nth == limit) { std::sort(first, limit, cmp); return; }`

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `nth == limit` is a range error, just as it would be in `nth_element`. I tried to edit the answer to make that more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

You want to `partial_sort` *first*. Then, while elements are not equal, return them. If you meet a sequence of equal elements which is larger than the remaining k, shuffle and return first k. Else return all and continue.

Comment: If you do a partial_sort and there are equal elements, it is not guaranteed that elements equal to the last element in the sorted part of the container will be at the beginning of the unsorted part of the array. So you might miss them. ("equal" here to be interpreted in the sense of 25.4(4) equivalence classes)

Comment: @rici: Doesn't matter, because you only sorted the first k elements you need. The fact that the order is undefined is an advantage, not a limitation- hell, partial_sort implements it for you here.

Comment: Thanx, but I think I have to agree with @rici: As an example take k=1 of n=3: A(2.7), B(1.2), C(2.7)....assuming partial_sort is stable (and the values in brackets define the comparator), then it would do nothing and you would just return A. However, we need A,B fifty:fifty.

Comment: @user1814663: `partial_sort` is probably not stable (stability adds an extra cost), however it's deterministic which does not suit your problem.

Comment: @Matthieu M. I know, this was just to construct an easy counterexample to this post, underlining what rici said....as partial_sort is not stable, there is a chance it will ALWAYS return B instead of A...but as you said never randomly fifty:fifty

Comment: @DeadMG: the point is not whether or not `partial_sort` is stable: it is that it guarantees nothing about non-sorted elements. If you want a random selection of elements equivalent to the least-good element selected, you need to find all of the equivalence class, because you cannot guarantee after partial_sort that they will be at the beginning of the unsored segment. They might be anywhere in the unsorted segment.

Answer (score 2):

Not fully understanding your issue, but if you it were me solving this issue (if I am reading it correctly) ...

Since it appears you will have to traverse the given object anyway, you might as well build a copy of it for your results, sort it upon insert, and randomize your "equal" items as you insert.

In other words, copy the items from the given container into an STL list but overload the comparison operator to create a B-Tree, and if two items are equal on insert randomly choose to insert it before or after the current item.

This way it's optimally traversed (since it's a tree) and you get the random order of the items that are equal each time the list is built.

It's double the memory, but I was reading this as you didn't want to alter the original list. If you don't care about losing the original, delete each item from the original as you insert into your new list. The worst traversal will be the first time you call your function since the passed in list might be unsorted. But since you are replacing the list with your sorted copy, future runs should be much faster and you can pick a better pivot point for your tree by assigning the root node as the element at length() / 2.

Hope this is helpful, sounds like a neat project. :)

Comment: Thank you, it seems amazing what can be done with memory storage (as e.g. with hash_sets)...being a mathematician I tend to overlook things like that ;-) I'm however unsure what you mean with "create a B-tree" and that insert sort is significantly less efficient than usual sorts??

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind sorting the whole list, there is a simple answer.  Randomize the result in your comparator for equivalent elements.

```
        std::sort(validLocations.begin(), validLocations.end(),
        [&](const Point& i_point1, const Point& i_point2)
          {
              if (i_point1.mX == i_point2.mX)
              {
                  return Rand(1.0f) < 0.5;
              }
              else
              {
                  return i_point1.mX < i_point2.mX;
              }
          });
```